# How to highlight rows by searching multiple comma separated values in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to highlight rows with conditional formatting by searching with multiple comma separated values in Excel like below:

[image]

I can highlight with single value but I want to search with multiple values. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following formula in conditional formatting:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&$A4&",",","&$B$1&","))
```

Apply formating to range `$A$4:$B$13` or adjust accordingly

[image]

Comment: Thank you @basic for your response. But its working partially. When I put 11 its highlighting 1 and 11 which is wrong. How to avoid this issue? Reference Image: https://pasteboard.co/Jlz8wqN.png